# :hover not working what am i missing or doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: #1A2456;
    padding: 1em;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
}
h2 {
    color: #FF8B68 ;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
li a, h2 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FF8B68;
}
.how {
    margin-left: 31em;
}
.dropdown ul {
    display: none;
  
}
.workflow:hover .dropdown ul { 
   display: unset;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navbar">
      <h2> <a href="#">MONOGRAM</a> </h2>
      <li><a href="#" class="how">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="workflow">WORKFLOW</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <ul>
            <li>PHOTO EDITING</li>
            <li>VIDEO & FILMMAKING</li>
            <li>MUSIC & AUDIO</li>
            <li>VIRTUAL PRODUCTION</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">DOWNLOAD</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="gg-shopping-bag"></i></a></li>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

When I hover on the workflow link, I want to display the content of the dropdown menu which I have given a class name of `.dropdown`, but when I hover on the workflow link, nothing is happening.

Where did I go wrong? Is it the use of wrong selectors? If so, what should I use?

Comment: check specificity

Comment: `.workflow:hover .dropdown` selector do not work because `.dropdown` is not the children of `.workflow` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues that need to be corrected with your code.

First, you hide `ul` with `.dropdown ul` but never show it again in any condition.

And you are trying to select the **child** `.dropdown` of `.workflow` but it is not the child, it is **sibling**. So either you need to move the dropdown inside the `.workflow` or change the selector to `.workflow:hover + .dropdown`

But, when you use sibling selector, you are losing the ability to move over the dropdown menu because when the mouse leaves the `.workflow` the menu become hidden again.

So, I suggest you to move the `.workflow` class from the `a` tag to `li` tag to cover the children.

You can find the working example below. Please note that `li` has `position: relative` property and `.dropdown` has `position: absolute; top: 100%;` properties.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #1a2456;
  padding: 1em;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

h2 {
  color: #ff8b68;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

li a,
h2 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff8b68;
}

.how {
  margin-left: 31em;
}

li .dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

.workflow:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navbar">
    <h2> <a href="#">MONOGRAM</a> </h2>

    <li><a href="#" class="how">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
    <li class="workflow"><a href="#">WORKFLOW</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <ul>`enter code here`
          <li>PHOTO EDITING</li>
          <li>VIDEO & FILMMAKING</li>
          <li>MUSIC & AUDIO</li>
          <li>VIRTUAL PRODUCTION</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">DOWNLOAD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="gg-shopping-bag"></i></a></li>

  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are setting `.dropdown ul` to `display: none`, but you are not setting it back to default in `.workflow:hover .dropdown` since it is targeting the `.dropdown` class and not the `ul` element.

It's either you change `.dropdown ul` to just `.dropdown` or make the hover like `.workflow:hover .dropdown ul`.

---

Now for the main problem, …

Upon using Inspect Element, I noticed that the `.dropdown` class is not a child of `.workflow`, but it is an adjacent element.

To fix that, you should use the `+` selector, which selects the adjacent sibling or the immediate element after the first element.

Your code should now be like this:

```
.dropdown ul {
    display: none;
}

.workflow:hover + .dropdown ul { 
    display: block;
}
```

---

Furthermore, you can read more of CSS selectors here:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: thank you very much now i know what i did wrong ,and  i confused sibling with child .

Answer (score 0):

Use class of workflow in the li element it will work. like:

```html
<li class="workflow"><a href="#">WORKFLOW</a>
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: #1A2456;
    padding: 1em;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
}
h2 {
    color: #FF8B68 ;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
li a, h2 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FF8B68;
}
.how {
    margin-left: 31em;
}
.dropdown ul {
    display: none;
  
}
.workflow:hover .dropdown ul { 
   display: unset;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navbar">
      <h2> <a href="#">MONOGRAM</a> </h2>
      <li><a href="#" class="how">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
      <li class="workflow"><a href="#">WORKFLOW</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <ul>
            <li>PHOTO EDITING</li>
            <li>VIDEO & FILMMAKING</li>
            <li>MUSIC & AUDIO</li>
            <li>VIRTUAL PRODUCTION</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">DOWNLOAD</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="gg-shopping-bag"></i></a></li>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```